# Minimum blocks to be removed such that no water is trapped in water trapping

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

This was asked to me in Goldman Sachs interview.

We have an array where i<sup>th</sup> element denotes number of blocks(of fixed height and width) kept at i<sup>th</sup> position like in water trapping problem. We have to remove the minimum number of blocks from the top such that no water gets trapped when it rains.

The solution I came up with was we have to ensure that the final structure is such that some x<sup>th</sup> is peak and elements to it's left and right remains non-increasing till extreme is reached. We can do it for each element and find the minimum of all the results found.
One slight optimization I did was that I can check that whether any i<sup>th</sup> position can be a peak or not. Any i<sup>th</sup> element can be peak if there is at least one element to it's left and right which has the height lower that current position.

The interviewer asked me to somehow use the left and right array used in water trapping problem(ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trapping-rain-water/) which I wasn't able to do.
I was wondering if there was any better solution to the above problem.

Comment: Interesting problem. For clarification, can the blocks all be the same height and not trap water? E.g., does {3,3,3} trap water? If it doesn't trap water, I have a possible sol'n

Comment: Yes, instead of decreasing I should have mentioned non-increasing. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

We need to answer the question:

- Which column would make the best peak, i.e. the one where we need to remove the minimum number of blocks to make it decreasing (non-increasing) towards both sides?

To answer this, for each column, we need to answer the question:

- How many blocks need to be removed to make this a peak?

We can split this into 2 questions:

- `L(i)` = How many blocks need to be removed to the left?
- `R(i)` = How many blocks need to be removed to the right?

`L(i)` can be derived as follows:

- If the column to left is less or equal, the number of blocks to make that a peak would be the same as the number of blocks to make this is peak. Thus:

  `if (column i-1 <= column i) L(i) = L(i-1)`
- If the column to left is greater, we need to find the first column `j` to the left that is less or equal to `i`. Then the blocks to be removed (to the left) to make `i` a peak (`L(i)`) will be the blocks to be removed to make `j` a peak (`L(j)`) plus the blocks to be removed to make everything in between equal to `i`.

  This would be simple enough if we could just loop over the columns to get there, but to do it efficiently requires something a bit more complicated.

  Note that we only care about the *first* element `j` that's less than `i`, which means any element `k` to the left of that element `j` that's *greater* than `j` we don't care about at all (since anything that might've returned `k`, that is `k <= i`, will return `j` before it can do that, since `j <= k`, thus `j <= i`). What this also means is that we only ever need to process any given column once, since if we're looking through columns to find one that's less, everything we look through will be greater, and would thus be irrelevant for the columns to the right.

  This leads us to the following:

  - Keep an stack of increasing columns.

    Technical note: We need to store the indices of the columns in the stack, not the values of the columns, since we also need to know where the column is. For my example below, I just used the values for readability.
  - Using this stack we can quickly calculate any given `L(i)` by popping elements greater than column `i` from the stack and multiplying the difference and distance between the popped value and column `i`.

  Here's an example to make it less abstract. If we have:

  ```
  [2,6,4,9,5,3]
   0,1,2,3,4,5    i
   0,0,2,2,6,12   L(i)

  stack after 5 = [2,4,5]
  stack after 3 = [2,3]

  [2,4,4,5,5,3]   to make 5 a peak
  [2,3,3,3,3,3]   to make 3 a peak
  ```

  To make 5 a peak (`L(4) = 6`), we'll have `[2,4,4,5,5,3]` - that is, all elements between 5 and the next smaller element 4 should be made equal to 5, and all elements between 4 and the next smaller element 2 should be made equal to 4.

  To turn 3 into a peak from here, we need to add the above (`6`) to the blocks to remove to change all the 5's into 3's (which is `2 columns*(5-3) = 4`) and 4's into 3's (which is `2 columns*(4-3) = 2`).

  If we get a 1 after this, for example, we can do the same using only the 2 and 3 (since we already know the cost to make all the columns in the middle equal to 3).

`R(i)` can be derived in exactly the same way as `L(i)`, just with the direction reversed.

Finally we simply need to return the column that would make the best peak, which is `min(L(i) + R(i))`.

This takes O(n) time and O(n) space.

Here's some Python 3 code which does this:

```python
# x[-1] is last element of x
# We add an element to the start to simplify the code
def calc_L_R(a, L):
    a.insert(0, 0)
    stack = [0]
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if a[i-1] <= a[i]:
            L.append(L[-1])
            stack.append(i)
        else:
            rem = L[-1]
            while a[i] < a[stack[-1]]:
                j = stack.pop()
                rem += (j - stack[-1]) * (a[j] - a[i])
            L.append(rem)
            stack.append(i)
    a.remove(0)

def no_water_trapped(a):
    L = [0]
    calc_L_R(a, L)
    a.reverse()
    R = [0]
    calc_L_R(a, R)
    R.reverse()
    return min(L[i] + R[i] for i in range(len(L)))

print(no_water_trapped([4,1,4,1,4])) # 6
print(no_water_trapped([6,4,5,3,3,8,7,9])) # 7
print(no_water_trapped([3,3,4,3,3])) # 0
```